# PHP - Regex validate date

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate a date format in PHP "01/02" Day and Month. Anyway, i can't get this to work. Dose anyone know what i've done wrong in this case? It keeps saying my date is not valid for some reason..

```
if(!preg_match('/^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{2})$/',$postDate)) {
$array['error'] = 'true';
$array['errorMessage'] = 'Ugyldig dato (DD/MM)';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to match Day/Month (as you have written in your question) or Month/Day (as you have written in you correct seeming regex)?

Comment: oh lord, i got this all wrong! dude, thanks for seeing this, i must be blind! haha!

Comment: @nikic: Looks more like month/year to me. (unless the second number doesn't need validating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you figured out your main problem, but I want to point out that the "day" part of your date pattern is pretty broad. I'd use something closer to this:

```
([012]\d|3[01])
```

That doesn't stop people from putting in stuff like 31/02 (i.e. February 31), though. That can be fixed, it just makes the regex longer. Let me know if you care about that and I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the handsup Justin, i've just rewritten the regex, now it works great! Thanks anyway :)